# echo output not formatting properly

Tags: linux, bash, echo, expect

I am trying to setup a script to build expect commands to run inline with that script based on data i have pulled from elsewhere.

I need the output to look like this

```
send "get filename1.out.dat.pgp\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get filename2.out.dat.pgp\n"
expect "sftp>"
```

I am using the following code

```
while read filel
do
    echo 'send "get '${filel}'\n"' >> $ExpectCMMDSGET
    echo 'expect "sftp>"' >> $ExpectCMMDSGET
done < "$DirList"
```

but when i cat the file out i get

```
\n"d "get filename1.out.dat.pgp
expect "sftp>"
\n"d "get filename2.out.dat.pgp
expect "sftp>"
```

and when i look at in VI i get

```
send "get filename1.out.dat.pgp^M\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get filename2.out.dat.pgp^M\n"
expect "sftp>"
```

I have tried using sed to remove the ^M once the file is created before being used but it is not working.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `"$DirList"` contains carriage returns. You can use `sed -i "s/\r//g" file` to delete them from a file, preferably from your original input, but alternately from your created file.

Comment: Lol, of course i didnt think of that. i was so focused on the output. Thanks for that it worked like a charm